# SQLAlchemy filter all relationships

Tags: flask, join, filter, sqlalchemy, relationship

so I have these four tables

```
class ClimbingHallSectionModel(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'climbing_hall_section'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    climbing_hall_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('climbing_hall.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)

    walls = db.relationship('ClimbingWallModel', lazy='select', passive_deletes=True)

class ClimbingWallModel(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'climbing_wall'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    climbing_hall_section_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('climbing_hall_section.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    height = db.Column(db.Integer)

    lines = db.relationship('LineModel', lazy='select', passive_deletes=True)

class LineModel(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'line'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    climbing_wall_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('climbing_wall.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)

    routes = db.relationship('RouteModel', lazy='select', passive_deletes=True)

class RouteModel(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'route'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)
    line_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('line.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
```

I want to query all sections where the attribute active of the route table is true.

I tried the following query:

```
sections = (db.session.query(ClimbingHallSectionModel)
        .join(ClimbingWallModel)
        .join(LineModel)
        .join(RouteModel)
        .filter(RouteModel.active==True).all())
```

This query returns indeed only these sections which contains routes with the attribute active set to true.

However if I now acces the routes of one of the sections with `sections.walls[0].lines[0].routes`, I get all routes of the selected line including the routes where active is set to false.

For me it looks like that the filter only works correctly on the ClimbingHallSection level but then is not passed to the related tables.

Of course I could do something like this

```
sections = (db.session.query(ClimbingHallSectionModel, ClimbingWallModel, LineModel, RouteModel)
        .select_from(ClimbingHallSectionModel)
        .join(ClimbingWallModel)
        .join(LineModel)
        .join(RouteModel)
        .filter(RouteModel.active==True).all())
```

But this would return a list of tubles:

```
sections = [
    (<ClimbingHallSectionMode 1>, <ClimbingWallModel 1>, <LineModel 1>, <RouteModel 1>),
    (<ClimbingHallSectionMode 1>, <ClimbingWallModel >, <LineModel 1>, <RouteModel 2>),...]
```

I don't know if this is even possible but how can I "pass" the filter arguments to all related tables so that the a section would only contain theses wall which containing lines which contain only routes with active set to true?

Comment: When you invoke a relationship (`walls` or `lines`), you are in effect constructing and executing a separate piece of SQL logic, which does not obey (or understand, or know about) the filter of your original query. Perhaps constructing one or more `subquery`s and then coupling them to a main query might get you the necessary related table outputs?

Comment: On second thoughts, you might be able to proceed using the SQLA construct `.options(joinedload(Table.reln))` as part of your initial query. That ought to retrieve SQL-connected rows of the related tables, and be accessible using `.reln` collection.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (currently partial) demonstration of the joinedload option.

Change your RouteModel model so that relationships adorn the parent table:

```
class ClimbingHallSectionModel(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'climbing_hall_section'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    climbing_hall_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('climbing_hall.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)

    walls = db.relationship('ClimbingWallModel', lazy='select', passive_deletes=True)

class ClimbingWallModel(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'climbing_wall'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    climbing_hall_section_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('climbing_hall_section.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    height = db.Column(db.Integer)

    lines = db.relationship('LineModel', lazy='select', passive_deletes=True)

class LineModel(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'line'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    climbing_wall_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('climbing_wall.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)

    routes = db.relationship('RouteModel', lazy='select', passive_deletes=True)

class RouteModel(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'route'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)
    line_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('line.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)

    rev_routes = db.relationship('LineModel', back_populates='routes')
```

Then, this query ought to give you the related table rows you need, at least for `LineModel` table:

```
sections = (db.session.query(RouteModel)
        .options(joinedload(RouteModel.rev_routes))
        .filter(RouteModel.active==True).all())
```

For each section in sections, iterate `section.rev_routes` to access filtered rows in that related table. The joinedload concept does not work (AFAIK) in a sequence of chained relationships, but this may be a start.

Comment: @rosi I know you are a new user, but you should respond to this answer and let me know if it addresses your issue.

Comment: @CodeMantel thanks for you answer and sorry for the late response. I hadn't had time the last days to code. I tried your solution but unfortunately I don't get it working for the whole relationship chain. The reason why I need this nested object ist that I am using marshmallow to serialize the ClimbingHallSection object later to send it as a http response. Thats why the ClimbingHallSections should contain the correct ClimbingWalls and the ClimbingWalls the Lines and so on.

Comment: Maybe think about a composite solution, incorporating subqueries (that capture the filter parameters) into a main query that potentially uses the joinedload technique for some of the joins. If you're comfortable converting row objects into dicts (dealing with all your known data types for serialisation), you don't absolutely need Marshmallow.

Comment: I didn't get it running with subqueries etc. So my current quick and dirty workaround is the second solution where I query all tables and get a list of tuples back. Then I loop through this list and create my nested object. It's not nice and really ugly but it works...